# Convert CV Mat object to std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> without loop

Tags: opencv, vector, eigen, open3d

I have a RGB `CV::Mat` object and I want to convert it to `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` to be used in open3d pointcloud color, is it possible to do this without loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Please mind that placing Eigen vectors in std vectors requires special care. Please check the eigen [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html)

Comment: Thanks. According to the docs, the issues arise only with fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types and structures having such Eigen objects as member. So Vector3d is technically fine?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, provided you go the other way around:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> pixel_data(height * width);
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_64FC3, &(pixel_data[0](0)));
fill_the_matrix_as_you_wish(mat);
```